# GraphQL caching mechanism

Tags: caching, graphql, graphql-js

I want to use GraphQL to access data from different data sources (CSV, SQL Server, Web Server) . I want to know if caching mechanism is supported, so that when the connection is lost the data is still available? I see the data loader which is data batching to increase the performance of the query, but I do not know how data loader can do caching?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out [DataLoader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in support, but you need to remember that `graphql-js` (which I assume you're using) isn't a framework, it's just a library. You'd implement caching exactly the same as you'd do it with anything else - by surrounding your data-fetching functions with caching get/set behaviour.

I don't use caching very heavily with `graphql-js`, but if you've ever implemented caching before, it's exactly the same principle.